# How to graphically represent $\ddot x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

We know that given a differential equation:

$$\dot x = f(x), x \in X$$

The $\dot x$ is understood as the tangent vector on the solution trajectory $x$ lying in the tangent space of $X$

[image]

What about eequations of the type $\ddot x = f(x)$? Can we think of $\ddot x$ as the tangent vector to the tangent vector? How do you represent $\ddot x$?

Comment: You can write it as a system of first order equations and then draw a phase portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field of mathematics dedicated problems of this type is [Symplectic Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_geometry). One can define $p=\dot{x}$, giving you the following set of equations

$$\dot{\eta}=\frac{d}{dt}{(x,p)=(p,f(x))}$$

where $t$ represents the trajectory parameter as usual, and $\eta$ is now a special type of $2n$-tuple, where $n=\dim (X)$.